# Python iterate through an array inside json object

Tags: python, arrays, json

bit lost here... trying to iterate through this array in a json object:

```
{
"NULSBUSD": {
    "symbol": "NULSBUSD",
    "orderId": 33523092,
    "orderListId": -1,
    "clientOrderId": "54Re4e4iV0bCkIXKyth4Sc",
    "transactTime": 1659875121897,
    "price": "0.00000000",
    "origQty": "187.00000000",
    "executedQty": "187.00000000",
    "cummulativeQuoteQty": "50.10100000",
    "status": "FILLED",
    "timeInForce": "GTC",
    "type": "MARKET",
    "side": "BUY",
    "fills": [
        {
            "price": "0.26790000",
            "qty": "150.00000000",
            "commission": "0.00009529",
            "commissionAsset": "BNB",
            "tradeId": 669893
        },
        {
            "price": "0.26800000",
            "qty": "37.00000000",
            "commission": "0.00002350",
            "commissionAsset": "BNB",
            "tradeId": 669894
        }
    ],
    "delta": 0,
    "tsp": 0.264528
}
```

}

this code throws

> string indices must be integers

```
qty = 0.0
for coin in order:
for fill in coin['fills']:
qty += float(fill['qty'])
```

Any ideas how I go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers. Plus, what is `order`?

Comment: Are you iterating over the raw JSON - i.e. a `str` - or the loaded runtime representation - i.e. a `dict`?

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need:

```
qty = 0.0
for coin in order:
    obj = order[coin]
    for fill in obj['fills']:
        qty += float(fill['qty'])
print(qty)
```

You can do this in one line:

```
print(sum(float(fill['qty']) for coin in order for fill in order[coin]['fills']))
```

**Output:**

```
187.0
```

If you do: for key in order, key is a string here:)

Answer (score -1):

Here's using dataframe to avoid looping -

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("data.json") as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
 
for coin in json_data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_data[coin]["fills"])

df["qty"].astype("float").sum()
```